# How to identify the programming language of an application which is compiled?

Tags: macos, reverse-engineering

I just downloaded an application and I'd like to know in what programming language they have written it.

If it's Java there would be a JVM process running in background right?

I did:

```
% sudo ps -A | grep -i java
```

no result.

I remember from Linux that there was a tool which would search for strings in a compiled source but I don't remember the name anymore, do you know something like that?

Any suggestions how I could find out the programming language?

Comment: I believe the tool you were looking for is called `strings` (and I think it's also shipped with OS X or maybe Xcode).

Comment: @WanderNauta, I'm totally fine with that if you write that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it, thanks that's it.

Comment: It's not really an answer to your original question, though, is it?

Comment: @WanderNauta, I ran it, it showed me strings which I knew that those strings are heavy indicators for that language, it solved my question therefore it's ok but I'll let you decide.

Comment: you could have a look inside the application bundle. if it uses java, you will likely find a jar file inside it. you could also open the executable file with a text editor or search trough other files contained in the app bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilation is the process of translating a program from one language to a different language. With computer languages, just like with translation of natural languages, it is generally impossible to tell which language something was translated *from*, you can only know which language it was translated *to*.

For example, keeping with your example from your question, if a Java program is compiled to ECMAScript and then run, there will be no `java` process running. All you can tell about the program is that it is *currently* written in ECMAScript, but you cannot tell what it was written in before. Likewise, if you compile a Java program to native machine code, you won't be able to tell that it was a Java program before, you can only tell that it is a native executable. If you compile Java to CIL bytecode, all you can tell is that it is a CLI program, but not what it was before.

On the other hand, if you compile Ruby to JVM bytecode and then run it, there *will* be a `java` process running. But that does *not* in any way mean that the original program was written in Java. It only means that the *running* program is "written" in JVM byte code. However, the program could have been written in *any* language for which a compiler exists which van compile to JVM byecode. Or, it could have been written in JVM byte code itself, although that is highly unlikely. There are many languages for which compilers exist that compile to JVM byte code: Scala, Groovy, Clojure, Fantom, Kotlin, Ceylon, Ruby, Python, ECMAScript, C, PHP, Scheme, CommonLisp, x86 native machine code, Frege, Ioke, Seph, … I believe there are more than 500 languages implemented on the JVM.

Now, this is not *completely* true: sometimes, depending on the exact compiler being used, the compiler will leave certain detectable residual traces or patterns in the compiled code that allow you to at least guess at the source language. For example, the mainline Scala-to-JVM compiler will leave a `ScalaSig` attribute in the compiled `.class` file which contains signature and type information that cannot cleanly be represented in the limited JVM type system. Many X-to-ECMAScript compilers will actually put a comment with the name of the original source file and the name and version of the compiler at the top of the compiled output. And so on. Specifically, languages which need to keep a certain amount of runtime information about the original program around, e.g. for dynamic typing, dynamic dispatch, dynamic reflection, dynamic optimization, etc., will be easier to identify than languages which can afford to erase almost all types and names.

But that is not something you can rely on.

> I remember from Linux that there was a tool which would search for strings in a compiled source but I don't remember the name anymore, do you know something like that?

It's simply called `strings` and is pre-installed on most Unix-like operating systems, including OSX.